# How to match double and single quotes at the same time with the sed command?

Tags: bash, sed, quotes

I would like to change a string with a *string variable*. The string is made out of `'"+a+"'` (this is exactly the string, no extra quotes were added. For example having the string `"foo"` and the string `foo` my example is the second `foo`)

Is it possible to change that using the `sed` command?

I want to replace it with a variable. I have tried this:

```sh
sed "s#'"+a+"'#${var}#" 
sed "s#'\"+a+\"'#${var}#" 
sed "s#'[\"]+a+[\"]'#${var}#"
```

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `sed` expressions - you're missing the second `+` symbol after `a` :)

```
$ var=" else "
$ echo "something'\"+a+\"'cool" | sed "s#'\"+a+\"'#${var}#"
something else cool
```

Comment: @luis just to be clear, you don't need an extra variable like the answer you accepted. The pattern you used in your question works if you add the missing `+`.

Comment: oh, you are right! .I guess is hard to see typos with so many symbols in a line.Actually using brackets might not be bad idea sometimes haha.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a variable also for the search.

```
var=_FOO_
search=$'\'"+a+"\''
```

```
echo "mama${search}papa" | sed  "s#${search}#${var}#"
```

Output

```
mama_FOO_papa
```

The `$' '` is bash style quoting.

```
search=$'\'"+a+"\'';  echo "$search"
```

Output

```
'"+a+"'
```

Comment: You don't need `$' '` quoting here (it's fine to use, but it's not the only approach). For example `search="'\"+a+\"'"` has the same effect.

Comment: Nested quoting is really something, yes there are more ways to approach this issue.